# Turing machine loop and reject example

Tags: turing-machines

I'm getting confused on these both. Reject the string does a stop while loop the machine goes on and on.

My textbook has one example on a reject state and no physical one for loop:

Assume that no reject state was given. And I input a string

$1^{q_{1}}011$

After all the transitions the turing machine is now on the empty string $1011 \epsilon^{q_{8}}$ with no where else to go and its not on a accept state, so it rejects.

Now consider if its on q2 at string $0$ so $$10^{q2}11$$

And it cant go anywhere. Would that also reject? Or only if its on the empty string?

Now what is a loop? My idea is

$$1^{q_{1}}011$$

$$1^{q_{2}}011$$

$$1^{q_{1}}011$$

$\dots$

forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different way to think about it. Every step, the Turing machine looks at the current cell of the tape, then does the following:

- Optionally, move the head left or right
- Select a new state, *or* accept, *or* reject

If it accepts or rejects, it halts and doesn't do anything further. But this won't necessarily happen: it's also possible for it to get stuck in a loop it can never get out of. Imagine the following machine:

> State 0: if you see a 0, don't move, go to state 0
>   State 0: if you see a 1, don't move, go to state 0

It's never going to get out of state zero, it'll just stay in it forever.

It's possible for a single machine to do all three, depending on its input:

> State 0: if you see a 0, don't move, go to state 0
>   State 0: if you see a 1, move right, go to state 1
>   State 1: if you see a 0, don't move, reject
>   State 1: if you see a 1, don't move, accept

Given the input `0` it'll loop, given the input `10` it'll reject, given the input `11` it'll accept.

Comment: what if there is no reject state ? Like, what would be the default reject? If it doesn't go into accept state but halts ?

Comment: @TreeGaren There's no such thing. It can halt-and-accept, or halt-and-reject, but can't just halt: it has to do one or the other.

Comment: @TreeGaren (Some people call the two "accept" and "halt", confusingly, in which case just "halt" means "halt-and-reject".)